# Removing users from AD group given e-mail address in a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I have a CSV file of e-mail addresses. The CSV file has one column with the header `name`. I want to remove the Active Directory users associated with these addresses from a specific group.

Here's my attempt, but it seems like `$user` is not getting populated.

```
$data = import-csv -Path C:\Users\39415\Desktop\remove1.csv
ForEach ($name in $data)
{
   $user = Get-ADUser -Filter {mail -eq "$_"} | Select SamAccountName
   Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "group name" -Members $user.SamAccountName -Confirm:$false
}
```

Please let me know what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue I see right away is you are using a named variable in your foreach loop but then trying to reference automatic variable `$_`

To use the named variable, change to

```
$data = import-csv -Path C:\Users\39415\Desktop\remove1.csv
ForEach ($name in $data.name)
{
   $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -eq '$name'" | Select SamAccountName
   Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "group name" -Members $user.SamAccountName -WhatIf
}
```

To use the automatic variable, change to `Foreach-Object` (still can be shortened to foreach but the former is known as the "foreach statement"

```
$data = import-csv -Path C:\Users\39415\Desktop\remove1.csv
$data.name | foreach {
   $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "mail -eq '$_'" | Select SamAccountName
   Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "group name" -Members $user.SamAccountName -WhatIf
}
```

Also as I've shown you actually need to reference the name property of the `$data` variable.